# How exactly warmup requests works?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

we have observed a strange behaviour of loading requests that we would like to share to obtain a precise answer.

We enabled the warmup request handler from the day of introduction because loading requests take from 15 to 25 seconds.

We always used the old "always-on" feature and then we configured the "Idle Instances" slider in "Application Settings" to 1-Automatic (1 reserved instance) under the new billing system.

Everything worked well because the majority (not all, but this is documented) of loading requests were correctly routed to /*ah*/warmup.

Our application is used only during work times in Italy so that single reserved instance wastes money during the night and the weekends, so we decided, two weeks ago, to try to move the "Idle Instances" slider settings to Automatic-Automatic.

The bill decreased, but after that *all* the loading request are front facing request (or at least task queues/cron requests). In that two weeks in our logs the /_ah/warmup is *totally* disappeared.

After two weeks, we decided to revert the slider setting to 1-Automatic and the next loading request was on /_ah/warmup. Now we are stuck on 1-Automatic.

We searched the official documentation for this behaviour but we found nothing about it.

We found only this question [Reserved instances and warmup requests not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875460/reserved-instances-and-warmup-requests-not-working) that states the same thing.

So the /_ah/warmup servlet is supposed to be totaly useless when the "Idle Instances" settings is on Automatic-Automatic? Or there is something wrong in our application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the warmup is ONLY if you have idle instances.  If your one, idle, instance get's a single request, whether from a client or a cron job, app-engine will immediately call /_ah/warmup to spin up, and maintain one idle instance.

If you don't have idle instances, **or the latency bars set**, appengine will not send a warmup request.  If you are under a heavy spike, app engine will also skip warmups.

As to why the sliders are stuck, I am not sure, mayber you could disable the application and re-enable it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I understood empirically, but there is no documentation about it.