# Idle instances ("always on") in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a python app running in Google App Engine.  Since it isn't heavily/regulary trafficked, every time a new user visits the site 15 minutes after the last instance was started up (or however long they stay active since the last request), it takes a long time (4-5 seconds) for a new instance to start up and serve the site.  Subsequent page requests while the instance is active is around 30ms.

From what I understand, setting a minimum number of idle instances can alleviate this startup time.  Following the answer here:

[Reserved instances and warmup requests not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875460/reserved-instances-and-warmup-requests-not-working)

as well as the documentation page here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

I set the minimum number of idle instances to 2, as well as added

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

to the app.yaml file.  And even though the frontend instance hours are piling up as if the instances were always on, there is still a 4-5 second startup time when a new visitor accesses the site.

Is there something else I'm missing?  I'd appreciate any insight.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  Since enabling warmup requests via the app.yaml file seems to cause GAE to look for a page at www.myappurl.com/_ah/warmup/ (I got a 404 error logged every time I accessed a page the first time), I added an empty "warmup handler" to my main.py file for the _ah/warmup/ extension, per the suggestions here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/x7vcuNK48Xg

Now that that's in place I get very few 404 errors logged on _ah/warmup/, but it hasn't improved the amount of time it takes to serve a new request.

Comment: what is the idle time on GAE that makes an instance go dormant?

Comment: I believe it's 15 minutes, ever since they introduced sub-hour billing.

Comment: If it helps, when I enable the two idle instances, I see listed on the App Engine dashboard 2 'resident' instances, as well as 1 dynamic instance.  Could it be that the dynamic instance is being spun up when a new visitor accesses the site and taking the 4-6 seconds to do so, rather than using the resident instance?

Comment: If you make another request right after one finished, what is the time it takes?

Comment: Subsequent requests take usually take around 30ms, but they can range anywhere from 20ms to ~150ms.  That much discrepancy I can certainly live with, though